# How to get text from H1 tag in Selenium + Cucumber + Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to get an H1 text. The page is converted from markdown to HTML. when I using below code to get text using XPath:

```
element = driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/h1')
element.text
```

I am getting error:

```
<driver.find_element(xpath: '/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/h1')
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/h1"}
(Session info: chrome=62.0.3202.89)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:71:in `assert_ok'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/response.rb:34:in `initialize'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `new'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:83:in `create_response'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/default.rb:106:in `request'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/http/common.rb:61:in `call'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/bridge.rb:170:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:581:in `execute'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/remote/oss/bridge.rb:549:in `find_element_by'
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/selenium-webdriver-3.6.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/search_context.rb:62:in `find_element'
    from (irb):60
    from C:/Ruby23-x64/bin/irb.cmd:19:in `<main>'
```

Please, can someone correct this code or suggest another way to get the text value?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I click the url, the site briefly shows a 'loading' text, after that the h1 text you're looking for becomes visible. You can use a implicit wait to wait a maximum amount of time before a timeout occurs.

Example from the selenium documentation:

```
require 'rubygems' # not required for ruby 1.9 or if you installed without gem
require 'selenium-webdriver'

driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 10 # seconds

driver.get "http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading"
element = driver.find_element(:id => "some-dynamic-element")
```

Also, since there is only one h1 element present, you can use a simpler selector like the css selector `div h1` or the xpath selector `//div/h1`

**Original post**

The two xpaths in your question are different:
`/html/body/div[3]/footer/nav[2]/ul/li[3]/a`
and
`/html/body/div[3]/div[1]/h1`

Can you provide the website html?

Comment: Corrected it now, by the mistakenly posted output of another XPath.